# Calculate a checksum for a string 

Tags: c#

I got a string of an arbitrary length (lets say 5 to 2000 characters) which I would like to calculate a checksum for.

Requirements

- The same checksum must be returned each time a calculation is done for a string
- The checksum must be unique (no collisions)
- I can not store previous IDs to check for collisions

Which algorithm should I use?

**Update:**

- Are there an approach which is reasonable unique? i.e. the likelihood of a collision is very small.
- The checksum should be alphanumeric
- The strings are unicode
- The strings are actually texts that should be translated and the checksum is stored with each translation (so a translated text can be matched back to the original text).
- The length of the checksum is not important for me (the shorter, the better)

**Update2**

Let's say that I got the following string `"Welcome to this website. Navigate using the flashy but useless menu above"`.

The string is used in a view in a similar way to `gettext` in linux. i.e. the user just writes (in a razor view)

```
@T("Welcome to this website. Navigate using the flashy but useless menu above")
```

Now I need a way to identity that string so that I can fetch it from a data source (there are several implementations of the data source). Having to use the entire string as a key seems a bit inefficient and I'm therefore looking for a way to generate a key out of it.

Comment: -1 for completely changing the question!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Do you mean that the question got lower quality? Or did you just get grumpy because I modified it since you told me it was not possible and I need a solution?

Comment: I think it's bad form to edit the question to be something completely different. And of course now the question is self-contradictory.

Comment: It's not different for ***me***. If I can't have uniqueness (which is logical now that I think of it) I still need to solve my problem: To get a checksum which is practically unique (while it might not be theoretically unique which doesn't really matter for me, but unique enough to be usable)

Comment: Your confusing your problem with this Q&A nature of the site. You asked a specific question which was not, "how do I best solve my problem". Anyway, I'm over it now!  ;-)

Comment: I'm well aware of the Q&A nature. I've been here for three years after all. It might not be specific enough for you (as you seem to know a lot of algorithms), but I bet it's specific enough for the average programmer.

Comment: The (original) question was very specific and very precise.

Comment: What size of checksum did you have in mind? 16 bits ?

Comment: The question (both versions) is unanswerable. The 5-2000 char range provides part of the puzzle, but what range of the ASCII/Unicode will be used, how many _different_ strings to expect etc.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: It might be unanswerable, but it's not obvious to me since I'm not very experienced in this area. Hence the updates. I hope that it's better now.

Comment: L.B's answer with a crypto Hash seems to come closest, but I suspect you String.GethashCode() is good enough.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: The range of the code returned by `String.GetHashCode` might be enough, but it's not recommended to store it over time. The algorithm may change with any update (and has actually changed in a previous update).

Comment: @Guffa: the expected lifetime is one of the things of the things missing here. And since the OP will probably need to compare strings after a Hascode match anyway the range/collision rate won't matter too much.

Comment: The translations (and therefore also the key) will live as long as the application  unless the programmer starts using another framework.

Comment: This is going nowhere. Better backup and describe how it will be used.

Comment: It looks like you just want to use the string as a key into a data base. That is a solved problem. Let the database worry about optimising it. It will do it better than you can.

Comment: The data source can be anything, not necessarily a database. The source in the dev environment might be flat files while it's a database in production. There is no relation to a PK/Id in the view, just to the text itself. Hence the need to generate a key from it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

That's not possible.

If you can't store previous values, it's not possible to create a unique checksum that is smaller than the information in the string.

#### Update:

The term "reasonably unique" doesn't make sense, either it's unique or it's not.

To get a reasonably low risk of hash collisions, you can use a resonably large hash code.

The MD5 algorithm for example produces a 16 byte hash code. Convert the string to a byte array using some encoding that preserves all characters, for example UTF-8, calculate the hash code using the `MD5` class, then convert the hash code byte array into a string using the `BitConverter` class:

```
string theString = "asdf";

string hash;
using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create()) {
  hash = BitConverter.ToString(
    md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(theString))
  ).Replace("-", String.Empty);
}

Console.WriteLine(hash);
```

Output:

```
912EC803B2CE49E4A541068D495AB570
```

Comment: Is there a C# function for a checksum on 16 positions?

Answer (score 9):

You can use cryptographic [Hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) for this. Most of them are available in .Net

For example:

```
var sha1 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();
byte[] buf = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test");
byte[] hash= sha1.ComputeHash(buf, 0, buf.Length);
//var hashstr  = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
var hashstr = System.BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "");
```

Comment: @Guffa Of course, none of the hash function can guarantee uniqueness since they map from infinity to a few bytes. But they can be considered as unique. Which is why we can use them in commercial or military applications. Your answer doesn't answer anything

Comment: @L.B Make your mind up. Are they unique or are they not unique? Can't be both. The fact that hash functions are useful doesn't mean that they produce unique values. I am dismayed that an answer that is clearly incorrect attract up-votes. [But now I see that the question has been changed].

Comment: @DavidHeffernan never use digital signature. Since it can't be unique :)

Comment: @L.B So what. Question asked for uniqueness. The points you make in the comments are completely irrelevant.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Then you don't have to comment to my answer, just downvote and continue with other answers.

Comment: In fact I removed my downvote (hence my edit to your A) because it is now reasonable with the changed question

Answer (score 4):

**Note**: This is an answer to the original question.

Assuming you want the checksum to be stored in a variable of fixed size (i.e. an integer), you  cannot satisfy your second constraint.

> The checksum must be unique (no collisions)

You cannot avoid collisions because there will be more distinct strings than there are possible checksum values.

Comment: That's a pretty theoretical argument. With a crypto hash of decent size, collisions are rarer than hardware introduced errors.

Comment: I for one assume that things that have a chance of say 2^-256 simply never happen.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I'm a mathematician by training so perhaps that's my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this post is practically ancient, but I stumbled upon it and have run into an almost identical issue in the past.  We had an nvarchar(8000) field that we needed to lookup against.

Our solution was to create a persisted computed column using CHECKSUM of the nasty lookup field.  We had an auto-incrementing ID field and keyed on (checksum, id)

When reading from the table, we wrote a proc that took the lookup text, computed the checksum and then took where the checksums were equal and the text was equal.

You could easily perform the checksum portions at the application level based on the answer above and store them manually instead of using our DB-centric solution.  But the point is to get a reasonably sized key for indexing so that your text comparison runs against a bucket of collisions instead of the entire dataset.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

To guarantee uniqueness, for a almost infinite size strings, treat the variable length string as a set of concatenated substrings each having "x characters in length". Your hash function needs only to determine uniqueness for a maximum substring length and then generate a series of checksum numbers generating values. Think of it as the equivalent network IP address with a set of checksum numbers.

Your issue with collisions is the assumption that a collision forces a slower search method to resolve each collision. If their are a insignificant number of possible collisions compared to the number of hash objects, then as a whole the extra overhead becomes NIL. A collision is due to the sizing of a table smaller than the maximum number of objects. This doesn't have to be the case because the table may have "holes" and each object within the table may have a reference count of objects at that collision. Only if this count is greater than 1, then a collision occurs or multiple instances of the same substring.